# How to identify exact specifications of a HP laptop knowing its serial number?

Tags: specifications, serial-number

I'm about to buy a used HP laptop. The model is known (HP EliteBook Folio 1040 G3), but this model can be shipped with different CPU, RAM, SSD, screen, etc.

I'd like to know what **specific** hardware is installed in this laptop.
My motivation is simple; prices could vary significantly (consider 1920×1080 TN display with no WWAN antenna versus 2560×1440 IPS display with touch and WWAN).
In fact, I only need info about parts that are soldered on the motherboard and can not be easily changed.

The seller has also sent me the serial number of the laptop to let me find the information myself, but it seems I can't.

1. So I went to HP official site.
2. The only serial number search I found seems ["Check Warranty"](https://support.hp.com/us-en/checkwarranty) page.
3. I chose country of purchase and typed the serial number.
4. The site opened the page that shows warranty status.
5. From there, I can navigate [The Product Home page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-1040-g3-notebook-pc/8654820/model/8654821?sku=) shows only general information.
6. From there, I can navigate to Product Information → Specifications, and it shows me a general [Specifications page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-1040-g3-notebook-pc/8654820/model/8654821/document/c04936028), with all variety of components that could be in this particular model.
   For instance, this is what is said about the display, and this seems useless for me:

   > **Non-touch**
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit FHD+ Anti-glare SVA (1920 x 1080), 300 nits
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit FHD+ Anti-glare SVA (1920 x 1080), 300 nits with WWAN
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit FHD+ Anti-glare SVA (1920 x 1080), 300 nits with camera
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit FHD+ Anti-glare SVA (1920 x 1080), 300 nits with camera and WWAN
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit QHD UWVA (2560 x 1440), 340 nits
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit QHD UWVA (2560 x 1440), 340 nits with WWAN
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit QHD UWVA (2560 x 1440), 340 nits with camera
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit QHD UWVA (2560 x 1440), 340 nits with camera and WWAN
   >   **Touch**
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit QHD UWVA (2560 x 1440), 340 nits with camera
   >   14 in diagonal LED-backlit QHD UWVA (2560 x 1440), 340 nits with camera and WWAN

So, my question is, how do I find what **specific** parts were included in the very laptop which is identified by a known Serial Number?

Comment: Go to support.hp.com and type in the serial number where it tells you to to “identify your product for manuals and *specific* product information.”

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In this situation I have always used the [HP parts surfer](https://partsurfer.hp.com/partsurfer/) website, punch in your serial number and will list all the parts for that HP product specific to the serial number.

Comment: From the website: To protect the privacy and security of our users, we have upgraded our site to HTTPS. The unsecured URL will be removed soon, so please use our new URL: https://partsurfer.hp.com

Comment: Changed, thank you.